# Is it worth customizing an XMPP server? (vs. having client workers)

Tags: xmpp

I've been asked about the possibilities for writing an ejabber module for an internal application. I am opposed to the idea, but I'm not sufficiently familiar with xmpp to support my response, and perhaps I'm wrong.

When google did wave they chose xmpp; and I understand that choice; real time communication between multiple people. Same goal here.

...but it feels to me like a customized server plugin isn't the right answer.

The issues I see are:

1) You lose sync with the server development and have to go through merge hell to ensure security updates, patches, etc. on the server are patched.

2) Any heavy customization of the server means you're probably expecting to be passing special mark up messages to interact with the server plugin; that means you'll have to do heavy client customization as well.

There is an alternative route:

Standard XMPP server. two customized xmpp clients; one for the client and one for the server.

The server client opens a connection to the XMPP server and sits and waits.

Multiple front end clients open connections to the XMPP server and then use xmpp to open connections optionally: 1) to each other and 2) to the server client user.

The front end can then perform real time updates by talking to the server client. It can even subscribe to multiple server client users and have incoming 'activity streams' for multiple different concurrent tasks.

This has the advantages of:

1) You only need to solve the XMPP problem once (client library)

2) Your application server is never externally visible; only the XMPP server is externally visible, which is massive security win.

3) You can use whatever XMPP server infrastructure you want without any issue.

4) You will never have a server update that causes your application server to become 'legacy' and unable to use those apis any more (short of a complete XMPP protocol update).

Downside:

You application server client needs to be complicated enough to handle multiple requests, or have multiple workers or something (but this scales using resource fields and have multiple application servers from different machines connecting to the XMPP network).

...but, I'm not that familiar with the technology.

Is there any reason why the alternative I've suggested would be worse than a customized xmpp server?

Comment: You have gone into great detail with regards to the potential solutions using XMPP, but what is missing is the actual problem description you are trying to solve.  This would go a long way to getting some help from people with XMPP experience.  For instance, your 2 arguments against plugins don't make much sense to me.  If the server is designed for plugins and plugins solve your problem, then write a plugin.  A plugin is not heavy customization, it is an extension and should generally be forward compatible.

Comment: I don't see it as particularly relevant but something along the lines of a real time collaborate whiteboard, where the client communicates draw actions via xmpp to the server, and the plugin persists them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMPP is used in Google Wave/Wave in a Box only for Federation, i.e. only for server to server communications. This is in order to take advantage of existing XMPP capabilities like discovery protocol. The messages are transported in binary form between servers inside XMPP packets. The Web clients use WebSockets/Socket.IO to communicate with the server. Actually that was the reason to argue about developing an alternative pure HTTP based Federation protocol.

Comment: really? sorry, my mistake. I thought the frontend ran as some kind of xmpp client via websockets. My bad; my comments about wave pretty much irrelevant then.